# Main window not responding after adding QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I'm currently making an AI to "Snake". After adding `QPushButton` to my `QMainWindow` there is no response from window for pressing any key.

```
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
   g->key_event(event);
}
```

That's how I'm injecting `QKeyEvent` into my game class. Everything works without any `QPushButton`.

Comment: The button might have the focus and therefore receive the events.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, and from your description it's rather hard to understand what is not working, and what you expect. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask] first, then improve your question to increase your chances of getting useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the problem is related to your override method not passing the call up to the superclass.  You might want to do it like this, instead:

```
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    QMainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(event);
    g->key_event(event);
}
```